# Proof verification: if $a_n, b_n>0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=L_1$ with $L_1>0$, then if $\sum a_n$ converges, so does $\sum b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, solution-verification

I'm trying a proof technique I'm not used to for limits on fractions, which attempts to avoid an epsilon-delta approach similarly to how the single variable chain rule is proved in baby Rudin, and I was wondering if it works. Any help or tips are very welcome!

> **Statement:** If $a_n, b_n>0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L_1$ with $L_1 > 0$, then if $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$ converges, so does $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} b_n$

Proof: Suppose $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} a_n$ converges to $L_a$.

Since $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L_1$, we have $$a_n = b_n(L_1 + \varepsilon(n))$$ with $\varepsilon(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore, $$ \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} a_n = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} b_n(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a, $$

so $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a,$$

and therefore,

$$\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\frac{L_a+\mu(n)}{L_1 + \varepsilon(n) } ,$$ where $\mu(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore, letting $n \to \infty$ results in $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i = \frac{L_a}{L_1}$, so $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}b_n$ converges. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Your proof appears to fail if $L_1 = 0$.

Comment: @ClementYung ah, thanks for catching that! $k$ was a placeholder, i forgot to change it to $L_1$. It's updated now. I've also updated the premise, thanks for the comment!

Comment: if $a_n \neq 0$, then write $b_n = \frac{b_n}{a_n} \times a_n$ and proceed

Comment: It seems like you treated $L_1+\varepsilon(n)$ as a constant (you factored it out of the partial sums) after you deduced that $\sum b_n(L_1+\varepsilon(n))=L_a$. This is not justified in your argument. Moreover, your summation index changed from $n$ to $i$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=l$ ; Prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges iff $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207734/lim-limits-n-to-infty-fraca-nb-n-l-prove-sum-limits-k-1-infty)

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks for the link! Note: the linked post offers an epsilon-delta proof, which I am attempting to avoid in trying out this technique, but the reference is appreciated!

Comment: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_n(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a$ does not imply $\sum_{i=1}^nb_n=\frac{L_a+\mu(n)}{L_1 + \varepsilon(n) }$

Comment: At AlannRosas and DougM: thank you very much for the comments, I will attempt to fix these problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $ \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} a_n = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} b_n(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a $, so $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a$

Actually, you should have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1+\epsilon(\color{red}{i}))=L_a$$

(note the red colored $i$ inside the sum).

---

Also, even  if the continuation would be correct, you are jumping over a lot of steps.

> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1 + \varepsilon(n)) = L_a$, and therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\frac{L_a+\mu(n)}{L_1 + \varepsilon(n) } $, where $\mu(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

This is a big leap. I don't see where you get the  latter expression from the former. You really should expand this out to explain exactly how the limit implies that the sum is equal to $\frac{L_a+\mu(n)}{L_1 + \varepsilon(n)}$, and explain exactly what $\mu(n)$ is.

Comment: I think the OPs inadvertent summation index change led them to conclude that $L_1+\varepsilon(n)$ is constant in the eyes of the summation.

Comment: @AlannRosas Probably, yeah. But I still wanted to point out that skipping over too many steps is not ok when writing proofs.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!

Comment: seems like I'll actually need an inequality to obtain bounds on $L_1 + \epsilon(i)$

Comment: I have one confusion: when OP says $a_n=b_n(L_1+\epsilon (n))$, it is understood that the equality holds as $n\to \infty$ (which results in $\epsilon (n)\to 0$) so the equality is true for "large $n$" and hence we can't put $n=1$ and say that $a_1=b_1(1+\epsilon (1))$. Is my understanding correct? Thanks. With the understanding colored $i$ part in this answer confuses me.

Comment: @Koro changing the name of the variables, we get $a_i = b_i(L_1 + \epsilon(i))$ with $\epsilon(i) \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$, true for any $i$ or $\epsilon(i)$. Only then can we produce the summation: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1+\epsilon(i))$, which is always true no matter the size of $\epsilon(i)$ or $i$ or $n$, but my mistake was to conclude instead $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(L_1+\epsilon(n))$

Comment: Or, the equality is true for any $n\in \mathbb N$, which means that $\epsilon (n)$ is simply a sequence which converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. With this understanding, the answer makes sense to me.

Comment: @Koro No, we can say $a_1=b_1(L_1+\varepsilon(1))$. By definition, this is true, because by definition, $\varepsilon(n) = \frac{a_n}{b_n} - L_1$. For large values of $n$, it is also true that $\varepsilon(n)$ is *small*, (and this is not necessarily true for small values of $n$), but the equation holds for all $n$.

Comment: My confusion is clear now. So my second comment is right. Thank you so much.  :)

Comment: @Koro Exactly, $\varepsilon(n)$ is simply some sequence that converges to $0$. In fact, that is *all* we know of $\varepsilon(n)$.